# Bash: Find all zip files, unzip them with password

Tags: bash

I have a directory with a bunch of zip archives (mixed in with other files) that are encrypted with the same password.  I want to find all the zip files and unzip them in the directory that the zip file is located in.

So far I have:

```
find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'unzip -pPASSWORD -d `dirname {}` {}' ';'
```

But I get the error

```
error:  must specify directory to which to extract with -d option
```

All help appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Apart from there not being a path specified for `find` to search in, what you write works fine for me (macOS).

Comment: I'm on a linux machine :(

Comment: The command you wrote works for me (ubuntu).

Comment: The command works just as fine for me on Linux (Raspbian).

Comment: Does the filename or directory it's in contain spaces?

Comment: Does any of your directory start with `-` ? Because I get the same error with this command `find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'unzip -PPASSWORD -d  -test {}' ';'`

Comment: figured it out.  The password option is capital `P` not lowercase.  I had a lowercase `p`

Comment: Попробуйте use xargs

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, also see my comment in the scripts how will it work:-

```
find -type f -name "*.zip" > zipfiles.txt

while read zipfilePath
do
   directorypath=${zipfilePath%/*}
   #get the path and separate the zipfile name
   zipfile=${zipfilePath##*/}
   #get the zipfile name from path
   cd $directorypath
   unzip -pPASSWORD $zipfile
done < zipfiles.txt
rm -rf zipfiles.txt
```